# Linker preventing MvvmCross MvxApplication Initialize being called

Tags: mvvmcross

I have updated my Target Android Api to Android 12 (API 31) so our app can be accepted in the PlayStore. This meant that the Android X packages had to be updated as well.

However, our `MvxApplication` `Intialize` override is no longer called, meaning we can not call `RegisterCustomAppStart`, so the app gets stuck on the splash screen.

This only happens when Linker (Link SDK assemblies only) is enabled. When it is disabled, everything works fine.

I find it impossible to determine what is happening under the hood with MvvmCross startup process, and therefore determine what may be linked out. I have included as many classes and methods as I can think of in our "LinkerPleaseInclude" file, but that is really stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Chucky Sorry but I can't remember. I'm now rebuilding the app in Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

ADB will output the missing method at runtime. It is indeed stabbing in the dark. It's more of a Xamarin issue than an MvvmCross issue.

The [Custom Linker Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker) is a superior alternative to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs. I use this XML to prevent linking out key MvvmCross bits with an Android MvvmCross 8.x app:

```xml
<assembly fullname="MvvmCross">
    <type fullname="MvvmCross.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector" />
    <type fullname="MvvmCross.Core.MvxSettings" />
    <type fullname="MvvmCross.Core.MvxStringToTypeParser" />
    <type fullname="MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader" />
    <type fullname="MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxSavedStateConverter" />
    <type fullname="MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxAppStart`1" />
</assembly>
```

Here is a full example from an Android app built with MvvmCross 8.0.2. The idea is to keep only what is needed. For example, remove the `NumberPicker` parts if you don't use that widget in your app.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
  This file prevents the Xamarin.Android Linker from removing code from the final executable.

  C# Properties are implemented as two methods: get_PropertyName + put_PropertyName
  C# Events are implemented as two methods: add_EventName + remove_EventName
  C# Constructors are implemented as such:
      default: .ctor
      string parameter: System.Void .ctor(System.String)
      
  See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker for more information.
  -->
<linker>

    <!-- Mono.Android -->
    <assembly fullname="Mono.Android">
        <type fullname="Android.Views.View">
            <method name="get_Text" />
            <method name="put_Text" />
            <method name="get_ContentDescription" />
            <method name="put_ContentDescription" />
            <method name="add_Click" />
            <method name="remove_Click" />
            <method name="add_LongClick" />
            <method name="remove_LongClick" />
            <method name="Invalidate" />
        </type>
        <type fullname="Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs">
            <method name="System.Void .ctor(System.Boolean)" />
            <method name="get_Handled" />
            <method name="put_Handled" />
        </type>
        <type fullname="Android.Widget.TextView">
            <method name="add_AfterTextChanged" />
            <method name="remove_AfterTextChanged" />
        </type>
        <type fullname="Android.Widget.NumberPicker">
            <method name="get_Value" />
            <method name="put_Value" />
            <method name="add_ValueChanged" />
            <method name="remove_ValueChanged" />
        </type>
        <type fullname="Android.Widget.NumberPicker.ValueChangeEventArgs">
            <method name="get_Picker" />
            <method name="put_Picker" />
            <method name="get_OldVal" />
            <method name="put_OldVal" />
            <method name="get_NewVal" />
            <method name="put_NewVal" />
        </type>
    </assembly>

    <!-- netstandard -->
    <assembly fullname="netstandard">
        <type fullname="System.TimeSpan" >
            <method name="get_Hours" />
            <method name="get_Minutes" />
            <method name="get_Seconds" />
        </type>
    </assembly>

    <!-- Google Material Design Components -->
    <assembly fullname="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material">
        <type fullname="Google.Android.Material.TextField.TextInputLayout">
            <method name="get_Hint" />
            <method name="set_Hint" />
            <method name="get_Error" />
            <method name="set_Error" />
        </type>
        <type fullname="Google.Android.Material.TextField.TextInputEditText">
            <method name="get_Text" />
            <method name="set_Text" />
        </type>
    </assembly>

    <!-- MvvmCross -->
    <assembly fullname="MvvmCross">
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector" />
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.Core.MvxSettings" />
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.Core.MvxStringToTypeParser" />
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader" />
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxSavedStateConverter" />
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxAppStart`1" />
    </assembly>
    
    <!-- Xamarin.AndroidX.Core -->
    <assembly fullname="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core">
        <type fullname="AndroidX.Core.App.CoreComponentFactory" />
    </assembly>

</linker>
```